# PHP/MySQL: How to save media player playlist order

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, playlist

I am currently building a web application (a media player) using Javascript, PHP and MySQL. It will be used to upload videos and store them into a playlist, which can then be used by the user to place the videos in the desired order.

Uploaded files a saved in a MySQL database (id, title, file name and location, ...). The question is, how can I save the order in which the user puts the playlist?

I don't think adding a "position" field in the database is a good idea, as too many queries will be ran with each update. I thought of a "next" field, which points to the id of the next video in the list, which would "only" require a maximum of 3 queries for each update (right?).

Is there a better way to store the order of the playlist? It doesn't particularly have to be in the database, it could be a text file as well I suppose.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Having next field, it 'll make bit complex to manage and having position field I don't think it 'll make considerable delay in query execution.

Comment: Without a "position" field, for example, how would you display the videos in order on the playlist page, or how would you know which video is first/last video of the playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a 'position' field would be OK. You could update it with one statement after changing a track position, like this:

```
UPDATE track SET position=(CASE 
    WHEN position > :oldPos AND position <= :newPos THEN position - 1 
    WHEN position < :oldPos AND position >= :newPos THEN position + 1
    WHEN position = :oldPos THEN :newPos
    ELSE position
) WHERE playlist_id = :playlist_id
```

When inserting a new track just set :oldPos to a big value (bigger than any position on the list, so for example list length + 1) and :newPos to inserted track position, when removing a track set :oldPos to removed track position and :newPos to a big value.

Comment: Yes, but you would also have to change the position of all the videos AFTER that one, right?

Comment: When moving a video on a playlist, you just need to change track positions for videos between old and new position. When adding or removing a video that UPDATE still works, you just need to set one of params to a value bigger than list length, that will make it update all the positions of later tracks.

Comment: Query is missing `END` in `CASE` condition. Should work with `ELSE position END` instead of `ELSE position` I think.

Comment: Your query works nicely for removing a video from a playlist. I am stuck at removing a video which is listed multiple times at different positions on the same playlist. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

The stack approach (i.e. using A next field) isn't a good idea because if you needed to insert a video in the middle of a playlist then you need to chase through your next.

The easiest method would be to just use a position field. when you re-order you will change the same amount of information as a stack approach but there will be much less computation needed.

Comment: I don't think so, if you insert a video in the middle of the playlist you only have to change 3 "next" attributes:
- the one of the moved video itself
- the one of the video that used to be before the moving video
- the one of the video which is now before the moved video

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would make a directory for each user and save a XML files (storing the path and name of the file) containing playlists or store them in a DB (users,playlists(id,id_user,name),media(id,description,path), x_playlists_media(id,id_playlist,id_media,position).